# Querying Other-Domain Members of LDAP Group

Tags: active-directory, ldap

My LDAP Group, `TestGroup`, has a domain of `A`. It contains members from domains `A`, `B` and `C`.

When I query for **all** members of `TestGroup`, it only returns the members from the `A` domain - the domain of the group.

How can I query for all members of the `TestGroup`, regardless of domain?

Comment: A few questions - What type of LDAP server are you querying? What does your directory architecture look like? What LDAP query syntax are you currently using? Keep in mind, each LDAP query needs some BaseDN as a starting point of your search. If the BaseDN only encompasses one domain, you will only receive results for that particular domain.

Comment: It's an `ldaps` server. Not sure of hierarchy. Syntax: `(&(objectcategory=user)(memberOf='<group DN">'))`. `baseDn` is high enough that it should be find the users.

Answer (score 0):

Your current filter is looking for all `user` objects that are directly a member of the group.  You need to get the group object, and enumerate the `member` property.  This will give you distinguished names for every member.  If you need to access the member's object, then you will have to search for that using something like (distinguishedName=).

This isn't easy.  You will have to decide whether or not you want to recursively get the members.  I'm pretty sure the users from the other domains are represented by dummy objects in the foreign security principal container.

Comment: What's the alternative? Add people to a DL only if they share the group's domain?

Comment: @Kevin I don't think there is an alternative, it's just messy.

Comment: I was hoping to resolve this issue via updating the Spring LDAP Config file, but apparently I'll need code updates, yea?